# How to modify WSDL file and pass the same to SOAP request

Tags: soap, wsdl

I want to modify the WSDL file, say "soap:address" element in it.

```
<service name="SessionCreateRQService">
   <port name="SessionCreatePortType" binding="tns:SessionCreateSoapBinding">
       <soap:address location="https://webservices.sabre.com"/>
   </port>
</service>
```

once it is done, pass the modified WSDL file during SOAP Request Calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it.

all you need to do is, pass location as a parameter while making a client call.

```
Client(URL, location='https://sws-crt.cert.sabre.com/')
```

No need of editing the WSDL file